# Magento2: Programmatically create bundle product

Tags: magento2, php, bundled-product

I'm trying to programmatically create a bundled product using the following link as a reference:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/Bundle/Api/ProductServiceTest.php

I'm adding the bundle product first, without any options, then loading it out of the database in order to add the linked products.

Here's an example of the array I'm using:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Test option
            [required] => 1
            [type] => radio
            [position] => 0
            [product_links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => test-simple
                            [qty] => 1
                            [position] => 0
                            [is_default] => 
                            [price] => 0
                            [price_type] => 1
                            [can_change_quantity] => 0
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

And here's my code to add the relation:

```
    $bundleProduct = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productID);
    $bundleProduct->getExtensionAttributes()->setBundleProductOptions($bundleOptions);
    $bundleProduct->save();
```

However, this does not add any linked product to the bundle product. Doesn't anyone have an idea what I'm missing? As the documentation for Magento2 is very limited at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass \Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface to setBundleProductOptions().

example code:

```
$productRepository = $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$product = $productRepository->get('product_sku', true);
$data = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Test option
        [required] => 1
        [type] => radio
        [position] => 0
        [product_links] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [sku] => test-simple
                        [qty] => 1
                        [position] => 0
                        [is_default] => 
                        [price] => 0
                        [price_type] => 1
                        [can_change_quantity] => 0
                    )
            )
    )
); // like in your example

    $options = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $optionData) {
        if (!(bool)$optionData['delete']) {
            $option = $objectManager->create('Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterfaceFactory')
                ->create(['data' => $optionData]);
            $option->setSku($product->getSku());
            $option->setOptionId(null);

                foreach ($optionData['product_links'] as $linkData) {
                    if (!(bool)$linkData['delete']) {
                        $link = $objectManager->create('Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterfaceFactory')
                            ->create(['data' => $linkData]);
                        $linkProduct = $productRepository->get($linkData['sku']);
                        $link->setSku($linkProduct->getSku());

                        $links[] = $link;
                    }
                }
                $option->setProductLinks($links);
                $options[] = $option;

        }
    }
    $extension = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
    $extension->setBundleProductOptions($options);
 $productRepository->save($product, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that code doesn't fit with the array/code that I've provided. The bundle product currently only exists on it's own, there are no Bundle Items, these are what I'm trying to add, so `getBundleOptionsData()` will not return anything, therefore the foreach would not be used?

Comment: Also, `$productRepository` is undefined, so I think the answer is missing some code.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, I've tried your example but I'm receiving the following error: Could not save child: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '357-132' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_relation` (`parent_id`,`child_  
  id`) VALUES (?, ?)"

Comment: It appears to throw the above error when there are multiple options, e.g Test Option, Test Option 2, which both have an array of product_links. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas @KAndy?